# Which jar brings this resource file, in Databricks

Tags: java, scala, jar, databricks, resource-files

I am running a notebook in Databricks, on a cluster that has many libraries that were manually installed.

In code, I am reading a resource file `files.txt`, which is a resource of a library I just installed.

The files has less lines than expected.
I'm assuming that the resource file is also in one of the other installed JARs.

Other than manually downloading the installed JARS, one by one, and examinig them - is there a way to tell which of the installed JARs on the cluster contains the resource file?

I'm reading the file like so:

```
val stream: InputStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/files.txt")
val lines: Iterator[String] = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream( stream ).getLines
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getClass().getResource("/files.txt")` Will return an URL, this should tell you where the resource is loaded from

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of resources for a given name by calling from all jars

```
getClass.getClassLoader.getResources("/files.txt")
```

If you have conflicting resources, this will return several entries.